# Implement pageable in mongo custom repository

Tags: java, mongodb, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My mongodb repository is as follows:

```
public interface ErrorLogRepository
        extends MongoRepository<ErrorLog, String>,
        ErrorLogRepositoryCustom{
}

public interface ErrorLogRepositoryCustom
        extends MongoRepository<ErrorLog, String>,
        ErrorLogRepositoryCustom{

// public List<ErrorLog> filterLogs(Date date, String type);
}

public class ErrorLogRepositoryImpl
        implements ErrorLogRepositoryCustom {
@Override
public List<ErrorLog> filterLogs(Date date, String type){
    //do some processing and return a list
}

}
```

I have some special logic that needs to be implemented. So I had to create the CustomRepository.
How can I implement pagination for filterLogs() in my custom repo?